# Using an array of 3d points to construct point cloud or surface in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, 3d-meshes, point-cloud

I have an array of 3 dimensional point objects, I can manipulate the input into this array into any configuration I want, for example, it could be a vector of floating point numbers, a vector of ints, etc.

Anyway, I want to display this 3d point cloud using OpenGL.  How should I go about doing this? I know enough that I can create a 3d cube from structured inputs but how would I go about creating vertices from this unstructured input?  If I don't need to construct these vertices how would I go about simply displaying these points as a cloud?  Any suggestions or advice is welcome.

Comment: `how would I go about creating vertices from this unstructured input?` What does this mean? Your input has to be in some structure, otherwise it is just some random garbage and will look like random triangles if you draw it

Comment: @tkausl my apologies, it isn't structured as in they aren't already vertices.

Comment: So what are they?

Comment: @tkausl just something like Point(x,y,z), simply data points.  They aren't structured such that they can be pushed into something like a vertex buffer, right?

Comment: What, you mean it is literally a textfile containing lines with `Point(1, 2, 3)` or what?

Comment: @tkausl well it's passed from another part of the program.  Okay, let's abstract that away.  It can be a text file containing, on each line, 3 integers.  This line is equivalent to one 3 dimensional point that I wish to display.

Comment: Well in this case, it is not in the correct format opengl expects (but it still has a defined structure! don't confuse a wrong format with no structure at all). First, you'd need to parse the textfile and convert these integers in text-format to binary numbers, then you need to convert them to floats and then upload those floats to the graphics card.

Comment: @tkausl thanks -- that's not too much help unfortunately.  I know that.  But how do I render a point cloud?  Not even a cloud.  How do I render a single 3d point?  I can take it from there.

Comment: To render a single (or multiple) point you'd need to pass `GL_POINTS` to your draw-call instead of `GL_TRIANGLES`. If you don't know the basics of OpenGL, then this will not help you too much, i know. But Since you already know how to draw a cube, it shouldn't be to hard to change it to draw points. Only change the draw-command to draw points and see what happens.

Comment: @tkausl simple as that aye?  My normally stellar google-fu was turning up some intense things -- I was considering importing another library to handle this for me.  Thanks m8.  If you'd be kind enough to create some sort of structured answer i'd accept it.  If not, i'll do that in the morning myself.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow If your talking about rendering point clouds then you might be looking for isosurfaces. Some techniques to get them into renderable formats are [marching cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) and [dual contouring](http://www.frankpetterson.com/publications/dualcontour/dualcontour.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, drawing points is as simple as drawing `GL_POINTS` instead of `GL_TRIANGLES`, you'll need one vertex instead of three of course.

Now to your non-structured input:

Of course it is structured. It may not be in the format OpenGL expects, but it definitely has some sort of structure, some format you're able to parse. In case of a text-format containing lines of three integers, you have to first parse those lines to get your three integers in binary format since ASCII (and other charsets) means nothing to the computer. After this, i recommend converting it to floats. Since OpenGL expects the data in one contiguous stream of data (at least if you don't do any advanced things with glVertexAttribPointer) you need to one float after the other, 4 bytes each, 3 floats per vertex -> 12 bytes per vertex tightly packed without empty space between them.

TLDR: Since you already know how to draw triangles or a cube (which itself is just built out of multiple triangles), you already know how the data looks OpenGL-expects and how to draw. So all you need to do now is convert your input data to the same format and draw your `GL_POINTS`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to this would be simply buffering the vertices into a VBO like you normally do, then rendering them as `GL_POINTS` instead of `GL_TRIANGLES` or `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`.

This will give you a cloud of dots, that you can rotate the usual way with your vertex shader.

If you want nicely sized circles, you should use a geometry shader to create a camera-facing impostor/billboard from each vertex and process those using a fragment shader, you could event texture these.

While technically you could do the same with the built-in `GL_POINTS` approach, it is not supported properly by drivers in my experience, so you have to resort to your own geometry shader.